# ListView.ScrollIntoView doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `ListView` in a page. I select a row and then scroll `ListView`. the `selectedItem` goes out of visible area. when I call  `ListView.ScrollIntoView( selectedItem)` it jumps to that row but the content of that row is wrong and it it filled with the last row that was visible when scrolled.

it is in xaml

```
<ListView                   
           Name="LstSurahText"
           SelectedValuePath="tblSuyaID"
           ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False" >

           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentControl 
                                Content="{Binding rtb}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

and yhis is in code behind:

```
LstSurahText.ScrollIntoView(LstSurahText.SelectedItem);
```

anyone knows why? and How to solve it?

**Update:**

I just understand  that contentControl make it work wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet and/or a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Did you try `listview.UpdateLayout()`?

Comment: Yes, I used listview.UpdateLayout() but no difference, just the content of contentcontrol in selectedItem not updated

Comment: What's the `rtb` you are binding to the `ContentControl`? I test your code with `string` and it works well. Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Did you set your string in content of ContentControl?  rtb is RichTextBlock with some span

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT: and another related thing, is it happens when virtualization in listview happens, I mean when I scroll somewhere that virtualization happens it makes it wrong.